# How can I fix path.join error? It's not accepting the output of a function, even when typecast

Tags: python, os.path

I'm trying to write a simple script that organises image files based on their label, (given by a separate csv file -- this has been imported as a list called 'trainLabels15list').

```
import shutil
import os
    
source_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Warner/resized train 15/resized train 15/'

def target():
  for x in trainLabels15list:
    if x[0] == file_name:
      trainLabels15list[x][1]

for file_name in filenames:
    shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), os.path.join(source_dir, target()))
```

if we print(trainLabels15list), this is what that list looks like:

```
[['10_left', '0'], ['10_right', '0'], ['13_left', '0'], ['13_right', '0'], .......
```

if we print(filenames), which is a list of all the files in the folder, this is what that looks like:

```
['8881_right.jpg', '8874_left.jpg', '8899_left.jpg', '8885_left.jpg', ..........
```

I keep getting the following error however:

> TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'NoneType'

I think this is referring to this part of the code: `os.path.join(source_dir, target())`, because target() is a function? But even if I force the output of target() to be cast into an int, or even string, it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `target` `return`s nothing, that’s the problem. You need to learn the basics of functions.

Comment: First I would debug this by splitting up the two join commands to find out which one throws the error. Then you should inspect your lists, because one of them has a None Type item in it, this is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @deceze, OK, I added the word 'return' in front of 'trainLabels15list[x][1]' in the last line of target(). It still comes up with the same error. Even when I typecast it, like return int(trainLabels15list[x][1]).

Comment: Then `if x[0] == file_name` is never true. Which would make sense, given your sample data.

Comment: @dosas , I know that it's referring to the second join command. The list trainLabels15list is a list of lists, of which the elements are strings. So why is it return None? I have done type(trainLabels15list[0][1]) to check and it comes back with String, as expected

Comment: @deceze , regardless of if it were ever true or not, it still comes up with the Type error mismatch. If it were never true it still shouldn't come up with that. My post here is asking if anyone knows how to get os.path.join() to work with outputs of a custom function, because that's where it seems to break

Comment: Your function returns `None`, that is the problem. Period, end of story. `join` doesn’t like `None` as an argument, so that’s where the error occurs; but the root problem is that your function doesn’t work as you think or want.

Comment: @deceze Ah, so the issue isn't with 'os.path.join' not being able to work with functions, it's because the function itself isn't returning something useable. Ok, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are looking for the `in` operator and you need to return something from `target` function.
Reconstructing from your (shrinked example) data:

```
import shutil
import os

trainLabels15list = [['10_left', '0'], ['10_right', '0'], ['13_left', '0'], ['13_right', '0']]
source_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Warner/resized train 15/resized train 15/'
filenames = ['8813_left.jpg', '8874_left.jpg', '8899_left.jpg', '8885_left.jpg']

def target(file_name):
  # filePattern == '10_left', fileValue == '0' and so on!
  for filePattern, fileValue in trainLabels15list:
    if filePattern in file_name:
      return fileValue

for file_name in filenames:
    targetFilename = target(file_name)
    if targetFilename:
      #shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), os.path.join(source_dir, targetFilename))
      print(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), '>>>', os.path.join(source_dir, targetFilename))
```

Out:

```
/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Warner/resized train 15/resized train 15/8813_left.jpg >>> /content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Warner/resized train 15/resized train 15/0
```

Comment: I think this is it! I will mark this as solved once it has finished processing and I can verify... fingers crossed!!!.....

Edit: Thank you Maurice, I wish I could kiss that shiny dome of your avatar! It did stop running (I have thousands of images); I wonder if this is to do with doing these things on colab/a mounted google drive. But thank you nonetheless, it's given me a lift.